# actionscript Number add and substract strange behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Well i just got a problem, with the simple following code:

```
trace( 0.01+0.05 );  // 0.060000000000000005
trace( 0.03-0.01 );  // 0.019999999999999997
```

I mean i just want 0.01+0.05 give me 0.06 and 0.03-0.01 give me 0.02.
Does someone have an idea how to retrieve the correct results ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imprecision is due to floating point arithmetic. 0.01, 0.05 and 0.03 are all *floating point literals*. Not every number (in fact, very few numbers) can be represented precisely in floating point.

For example, 0.5 can be but, 0.06 cannot. As a rule of thumb the first 15 significant figures will be correct.

For more details, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Ok thanks i will go to int and divide by 100 for displaying as i just want precision of 2.

Comment: That's a pretty common way to get round the issue. Btw, are you modelling money? If so then use a currency type, if available.

Answer (score -1):

trace(Math.format((0.01+0.05), 2));